# PipeInputStream and PipeOutputStream synchronous or asynchronous?

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, io, blocking

I'm reading a Java book I found a sentence that seems incorrect:

> When reading, if there's no data available, the thread will be **blocked** until it new data will be available. Notice that this is a typical **asynchronous** behavior, the threads are communicating through a channel(pipe).

Why does the author call the operation "asynchronous"? Shouldn't asynchronous imply that the thread will NOT be blocked until it receives new data?

Later Edit:

I run this code and it from the output it seems the behaviour is asynchronous.

Here is a part of the output: http://ideone.com/qijn0B

And the code is below.
What do you think?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author dragos
 */

class Consumator extends Thread{
    DataInputStream in;

    public Consumator(DataInputStream in){
        this.in = in;
    }

    public void run(){
        int value = -1;
        for(int i=0;i<=1000;i++){
            try {
                value = in.readInt();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Consumator.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            System.out.println("Consumator received: "+ value);
        }
    }
}

class Producator extends Thread{
    DataOutputStream out;

    public Producator(DataOutputStream out){
        this.out = out;
    }

    public void run(){

        for(int i=0;i<=1000;i++){
            try {
                out.writeInt(i);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Producator.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            System.out.println("Producator wrote: "+i);
        }
    }
}

public class TestPipes {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        PipedInputStream pipeIn = new PipedInputStream();
        PipedOutputStream pipeOut = new PipedOutputStream(pipeIn);

        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(pipeIn);
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(pipeOut);

        Consumator c = new Consumator(in);
        Producator p = new Producator(out);

        p.start();
        c.start();

    }

}
```

Comment: asynchronous means the writer is not blocked waiting for the reader(if there is free space in the buffer)

Comment: Uh! I just noticed the reader writes the same numbers the writer produced previous. I was thinking of synchronous as 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5, not 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 5 4 5 6 7 8 6 7 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does the author call the operation "asynchronous"? Shouldn't asynchronous imply that the thread will NOT be blocked until it receives new data?

Either this is incorrect or the author is talking about how the consumer thread would block but the producer thread would still run.  At the very least this wording is certainly confusing.

In any case, the `PipeInputStream` and `PipeOutputStream` streams share an internal buffer but otherwise are "synchronous".  If the buffer is full the writer will block and if the buffer is empty the reader will block.

Comment: it's confusing wording.  it could mean multiple things.  technically, yes, each individual stream is synchronous, however the movement of data _betwee_ streams is asynchronous.

Comment: How is it asynchronous @jtahlborn?  You mean because there is a read and write buffers?

Comment: yes, writer can write and return before reader sees data (up to a limit).  i guess, in a way, that's similar to any buffered stream.  your edit is a good clarification, though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do not show the whole text. If author says that producer is not blocked then it is asynchronous. Consuming is always blocking. (ok, sometimes you can check the availability of the answer, but sync/async is distinguished by behaviour of the sender). It will be blocking when buffer length is 0 then writer will always block and synchronization occurs. So, we can say that blocking/nonblocking (sync/async) is a feature of the channel.